# Android TextToSpeech

Tags: android

this is my first post and i hope you can help me :)

I'm developing an application for android, but i can't understand why my code don't work.
This application recognize the voice to do some comands.

```
public void OnButtonClick(View v)
{
    t.speak("Say the comand", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();//This is another function (Speech input)       
}
```

But i can't hear the TextToSpeech.

But if i try this code it works:

```
public void OnButtonClick(View v)
{
    t.speak(x, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    while (t.isSpeaking()); //It wait the end of the speech
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();//This is another function (Speech input)       
}
```

It's fine but if i try this code after the voice input it say nothing:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        b.setText(matches.get(0));
        Act(matches.get(0)); //Call the function to do a comand
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void Act(String cmd){
    if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("time") || cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("what time is it")){
        t.speak(x, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); //don't speach!
            while (t.isSpeaking());
    }   
}
```

I need to create a separate thread or there is a better solution?

Thanks to all :)

p.s. Sorry for my English

Comment: Did you try to use QUEUE_ADD instead of QUEUE_FLUSH?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your `Act(String cmd)` method a log command to see what is recognized by TTS (maybe Android cannot recognize commands):

```
public void Act(String cmd){
    Log.d("MyTTSApp", cmd);
    if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("time") || cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("what time is it")){
        t.speak(x, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); //don't speach!
            while (t.isSpeaking());
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with the way TextToSpeech works in Android.

When you call

```
t.speak("Say the comand", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

you're saying "start speaking this now please". But on the next line, you call a function which (I'm guessing from the name) opens a new Activity, backgrounding your first one before it even has a chance to start speaking.

A couple of ways round this: your current fix isn't the worst idea. Or, perhaps neater, instead of passing null as the last parameter to speak, pass an object that implements `onUtteranceCompletedListener`. When that object's method `onUtteranceCompleted` gets called, **then** call `startVoiceRecognitionActivity`.